# Change meaning of ["foo"] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make foo["bar"] return the bar field value normally, but if it doesn't exist, look it up in another object to find it there.  Is it possible to replace how [] works?

Why?  I am porting a 6 year old Javascript application to AngularJS.  In the existing app, there's (of course) one global variable (let's call it i2) that's used as a namespace that has everything in the app attached to it.

```
i2.models.fooModel.bar += 1; //and the rest of the app is similar
```

If that's not enough responsibility, i2 is also used as a registry of application "cells" like so:

```
var myCell = i2["MyCell"];
```

I'm breaking the global's fields into AngularJS services.  The cell lookup feature is also broken out into another servicer "cell registry" service.  Since this application has existing plugins that we'd like to be backwards compatible with, I'd like the code in the existing plugins like:

```
var myCell = i2["MyCell"];
```

... to still work (though deprecated).  Is there a way I can replace the [] function in i2 to look up the field in i2, and if it doesn't exist, look it up in another object (the cell registry)?

Comment: Your terminology is very confusing. Do you mean `var myCell = i2["MyCell"] || somethingElse["MyCell"]`?

Comment: Note that @remyabel's solution will treat falsy values such as `0` as "couldn't find it in `i2`". More general would be `typeof i2["MyCell"] !== "undefined" ? i2["MyCell"] : somethingElse["MyCell"]`.

Comment: Bracket notation is a key feature of JS, you can't change its behavior.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot *directly* and literally change the meaning of

```
i2["MyCell"]
```

because this is the design of the language and that typically can't be changed (and it would be terrible if you could). However, you can do something like this:

```
function lookupVar(key) {
    var value = i2[key];
    if(typeof value !== "undefined") {
        return value;
    }

    // do whatever you want to do now that it couldn't be found
}

var myCell = lookupVar("MyCell");
```

Of course this can be extended to handle other things than just a single variable `i2`. It might also not be needed at all and a simple

```
var myCell = typeof i2["MyCell"] !== "undefined" ? i2["MyCell"] : somethingElse["MyCell"];
```

might be enough (though it contains annoying duplication). If you know that if they key exists in `i2["MyCell"]`, it won't be a falsy value (`0`, `""`, `false`, …), then this will suffice

```
var myCell = i2["MyCell"] || somethingElse["myCell"];
```

Though it's not very future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) (don't work in IE8) or [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (not recommended for production code)...

> Is there a way I can replace the [] function in i2 to look up the field in i2, and if it doesn't exist, look it up in another object (the cell registry)?

Or just think about [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).